# form element not working in megnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

i have small-image class when i click on it megnefic popup open. in my megnific popup there is big image of clicked image and one button with other-form-opener class when i click on button other-form-div class with form comes up with my custom popup in this part when i click on form element they dont work as default.

```
 <div class="megnific_opener"><img class="small-image" ></div>


 <div class="megnific_popup_div">
    <img class="big-image">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="other-form-opener">more-info</a>
 </div>

 <div class="other-form-div">
     <form>
         <input type="text">
         <input type="text">
         <input type="text">
     </form>
 </div>
```

i give stucture of my html and i already cheked that there is not a z-index problem. 
so please help me thank you.

here is my demo in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QHh7W/

Comment: if possible can you please create a demo jsfiddle !

Comment: i added demo in jsfiddle and also give a link.@RahulGupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Magnific popup callbacks and move your custom html inside Magnific popup when opened and move it inside body when closed. You can check below working demo.

**[`jsFiddle demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/QHh7W/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Although i cannot get this working as per your that is opening both popups one above another in same window.

but in case you need it like this : open second after clicking from one.

http://jsfiddle.net/yDvvQ/5/

```
I have added different instance of megnific for both divs.
```

It is working for both popups, content and form both.

You can later amend it to add more popups or return to first from second.

Please review once and comment.

Regards

Comment: thanks but that's not working for me because same contact form is use for my every page of website.

Comment: can you explain bit more ?

Comment: can you explain how you intend it to use on your website ?